# How can I perform update method on a mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have my update button that performs a get request to fetch the data with the id and fills the slots. Then, using the form below I perform another get request to send a request to update the data.

```
 <form action="//updateBookRequest" method="GET" id="update-book">
        <!-- Book Name -->
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="name">Name</label>
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= book._id %> ">
           <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= book.name %> " placeholder="The Alchemist">
         </div>
        <!-- Author Name -->
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="author">Author</label>
           <input type="text" name="author" value="<%= book.author %> " placeholder="Paulo Coelho">
         </div>
        <!-- Language -->
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="language">Language</label>
           <input type="text" name="language" value="<%= book.language %> " placeholder="English">
         </div>
        <!-- Date -->
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="date">Date</label>
           <input type="date" name="date" value="<%= book.date %> " placeholder="">
         </div>
 
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="buttons">  
              <button class="btn">Cancel</button>
              <button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
           </div>
         </div>
      
      </form>
```

The route looks like this:

```
route.get('/update-book', services.updateBook)
```

And the services.updateBook looks like this:

```
exports.updateBook = (req, res) => {
  axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/books/${req.query.id}`)
    .then(function(response) {
      res.redirect('/')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
    }) 
}
```

But for some reason, it doesn't update the data.

When I do it in the postman, using the same 'http://localhost:5000/api/books/id', it works just fine and update the data with the postman body as it should.

But, it doesn't when I try to do it in the ejs file with the following section.

I can't seem to find where the problem is. Other functionalities such as adding new data, deleting the data using the id, displaying all the data seem to work fine.

How can I make it to update the data?

This is server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')

const connnectDB = require('./server/database/connection')

const app = express()

dotenv.config({path:'config.env'})
const port = process.env.port || 5050

connnectDB()

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/css')))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js')))

app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

This is the server/controller/controller.js

```
const Userdb = require('../model/model')

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({message: 'content can not be empty'})
    return
  }

  const user = new Userdb({
    name: req.body.name,
    author: req.body.author,
    language: req.body.language,
    date: req.body.date,
    description: req.body.description
  })

  user
    .save(user)
    .then(data => {
      // res.send(data)
      res.redirect('/')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || 'some error occured'
      })
    })
}

exports.find = (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.id) {
    const id = req.query.id
    Userdb.findById(id)
      .then(data => {
        if (!data) {
          res.status(404).send({message: `error ${id}`})
        } else {
          res.send(data)
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({message: `error ${id}`})
      })
  } else {
    Userdb.find()
    .then(user => {
      res.send(user)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({message:err.message || 'error while finding data'})
    })
  }

}

exports.update = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).send({message: 'Data to update is empty'})
  }

  const id = req.params.id
  Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {useFindAndModify: false})
    .then(data => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).send({message: `can't update ${id}`})
      } else {
        res.send(data)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({message: 'err'})
    })
}

exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id

  Userdb.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(data => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).send({message: `${id} is wrong`})
      } else {
        res.send({message: 'user deleted'})
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({message: `could not delete with ${id}`})
    })
}
```

This is server/routes/router.js

```
const route = express.Router()

const services = require('../services/render')
const controller = require('../controller/controller')

route.get('/', services.homeRoute)

route.get('/add-book', services.addNewBook)

route.get('/update-book', services.updateBook)

route.get('/updateBookRequest', services.updateBookRequest)

route.get('/delete-book', services.deleteBook)

// API
route.post('/api/books', controller.create)
route.get('/api/books', controller.find)
route.put('/api/books/:id', controller.update)
route.delete('/api/books/:id', controller.delete)

module.exports = route
```

This is server/services/render.js

```
const axios = require('axios')

exports.homeRoute = (req, res) => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/books')
    .then(function(response) {
      res.render('index', {books: response.data})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
    })
}

exports.addNewBook = (req, res) => {
  res.render('add_new_book')
}

exports.updateBook = (req, res) => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/books', {params:{id:req.query.id}})
    .then(function(userdata) {
      res.render('update_book', {book:userdata.data})
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
    })
}

exports.updateBookRequest = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/books/${req.query.id}`, {book:req.body})
    .then(function(response) {
      res.redirect('/')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
    })
}

exports.deleteBook = (req, res) => {
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/books/${req.query.id}`)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('deleted')
      res.redirect('/')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
    })

}
```

This is by far the whole code

Comment: are you using this **form with method="GET"** to send the update request?

Comment: @Aimsat yes i am

Comment: Can you share the code of this route: /api/books/${req.query.id} ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback in your update function. Also you can use {new: true} to get the updated document.

```
Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, 
  req.body, 
  {useFindAndModify: false},
  {new: true},
  function (err, data) {
    console.log(data); //check if the document is updated
  }
})
```

Also make sure your req.body is an object. if you are unsure, check req.body in console log